# Are there packages available on MiKTeX only (not on TeX Live)?

Tags: distributions

In the description of this new package:
[image]
is written that it is available in MiKTeX.
Why is it not on TeX Live, too?
Is it a matter of time, an author's choice, or what else?

I thought that the two distributions had the same packages, except for time lags, or that TeX Live was the most complete.

Comment: A number of packages are only in MiKTeX as texlive is more restrictive regarding the licence. Some of the missing packages can be installed from tlcontrib. (Sometimes it can also happen that a package has been overlooked,  one can then ask on the texlive mailing list)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you for your comment. I was only surprised because I have never experienced it before. If you would like to add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: It may also got the other way, here https://www.ctan.org/pkg/revtex4-1 comes to mind. MikTeX does not have it as it is marked obsolete.

Comment: as @UlrikeFischer says, but that one seems to be LPPL so shouldn't have licence issues, it may just have got missed

Comment: @daleif The other way for me is "normal", I was surprised of the contrary :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX huh?,

Comment: @daleif I tought the TeX Live was the more complete

Comment: @CarLaTeX in terms on proper licensing it is. But it is therefore also super large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MiKTeX typically contains a bit more packages as it is less restrictive regarding the license, TeXlive takes rather great care to include only packages which agree with the general principles and philosophy of the free software movement.
See https://www.tug.org/texlive/copying.html

Some of the missing packages can be installed from tlcontrib: https://contrib.texlive.info

It can also happen that a package has been simply overlooked, e.g. the example you show has no obvious license problems and it is not clear why it is not in texlive, in this case one can write to the texlive mailing list https://www.tug.org/mailman/listinfo/tex-live and ask about the status.